# Nginx 500 out of the var folder

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-config

I'm using nginx and I need help with the configuration. If I change the location from

```
root /var/www/html
```

to

```
root /spectrum/public
```

Where the index.html file is located I get the 500 error.

Take a look on the nginx default file

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root spectrum/public;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name pretected.com;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/index.html;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #   include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #   # With php7.0-cgi alone:
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #   # With php7.0-fpm:
    #   fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #   deny all;
    #}
}
```

With the default location `/var/www/html` I get the Welcome page from `nginx`, but when I change the location all I get is the 500 error.

I tried with the `/` and without the `/` at the line `root /spectrum/public`

Please help me to fix it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code says `root spectrum/public` not `root /spectrum/public` so which is right?

Comment: I said there that I tryed both ways, with and without the slash /.

Comment: Yes you did but which is correct as they mean completely different things and can't help with an incomplete or inaccurate picture

Comment: @ShawnC. I have my content that should run on my website under the spectrum/public folder. How I give this location to nginx?

Answer (score 1):

Perform this:

```
chown -R www-data /spectrum
```

Then change the document root back,

restart nGinx, see if you get a better result.

The files are not world writable. They are restricted to the owner of the files for writing.

The web server has to be run under a specific user. That user must exist.

If you decide to run it under a different user ID, then that user would need to be the effective owner of the files for proper privileges.

Creating a specific user would make it easier to recognize the files and consistent to recognize which ID to chown to new files and folders added to the site.

**By default the configuration of the owner is www-data**

Comment: It doesn't work, unfortunately.
That line return:
chown: cannot access '/spectrum': No such file or directory
so I run the same line without "/"(slash) at "spectrum" and apparently it works, but not helps with the nginx